# Error as I try to pass a row from a 2-D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

While trying to pass a row of a 2-D array, I get an error on the function call :

```
Tester.java:10: illegal start of expression
            function(arr[0][]);
                            ^
1 error
```

---

Can't we pass a single row from a 2-D array ?

```
class Tester {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char arr[][] = new char[3][3];
        arr[0][0] = 'x';
        arr[0][1] = 'x';
        arr[0][2] = 'o';
        arr[2][0] = 'x';
        arr[2][1] = 'o';
        arr[2][2] = 'x';
        function(arr[0][]); // ERROR STATEMENT
    }

    public void function(char arr[]) {
        for(char s : arr) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the data are arrays of arrays, and [] is used as part of a declaration of an incoming type, not of the root node of the array, in that context they are used as accessors to index into it.

`char arr[][]` is the declaration of an array of arrays of char's.  To access one of the inner arrays, you simply index into one of the base arrays, and the value you get back will be the inner array.

```
function(arr[0]); // CORRECT STATEMENT
```

Comment: Deleting my answer in favor of your better answer: 1+ up-vote

Comment: can you please simplify your answer. I didn't understand except that I need to pass like `function(arr[0])`